# Why I am getting -Wint-conversion even if it looks alright

Tags: linux, include

I have a problem with a Makro in my Code:

I get an error:

```
 :3859:2: error: passing argument 3 of '_csr_rd' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    [build]   CSR_RD(port_no, VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS(0), test2);
```

The hierarchy is like:
CSR_RD-> _csr_rd->csr_rd->
It is about the 3rd argument
If I put in there &value than the same error comes.

```
 vtss_rc vtss_venice_c_sd6g_ib_cal(vtss_state_t *vtss_state, vtss_port_no_t port_no){
..
// code
..
    u32 * test =0;
        u32 test2=1;
        CSR_RD(port_no, VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS(0), test2);
        if ((VTSS_F_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS_PLL_CAL_NOT_DONE, & value)) {
            // VTSS_E("VENICE_DEV4::SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS(0).PLL_CAL_NOT_DONE is not 0!");
            status = VTSS_RC_ERROR;
        };
```

This Makro is behind it:

```
#define CSR_RD(p, io_reg, value)                                      \
    {                                                             \
        vtss_rc __rc = _csr_rd(vtss_state, p, io_reg, value); \
        if (__rc != VTSS_RC_OK)                               \
            return __rc;                                  \
    }
```

and behind this is:

```
vtss_rc _csr_rd(vtss_state_t *vtss_state, vtss_port_no_t port_no, ioreg_blk *io, u32 *value)
{
    return csr_rd(vtss_state, port_no, io->mmd, io->is32, io->addr, value);
}
```

I try to understand it but its confusing...
It has 3 Parameter which are passed to the *csr_rd function which has 4 parameter. I also dont understand where the value vtss* is coming from ... i mean it should be somewhere where the Makro is defined........................................

also very nice stuff ist the following relation :D :
VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS -> VTSS_IOREG_IX -> VTSS_IOREG->VTSS_IOADDR

```
** 
 * \brief SERDES6G Pll Status
 *
 * \details
 * Status register of SERDES6G RCPLL
 *
 * Register: \a VENICE_DEV4:SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS:SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS
 *
 * @param gi Register: SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS, 0-3
 */
#define VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS(gi)  VTSS_IOREG_IX(0x04, 0, 0xe630, gi, 7, 0, 4)

** 
 * @param dev  - device id
 * @param is32 - is register 32 bit
 * @param g    - group instance, 
 * @param gw   - group width
 * @param ro   - register offset, 
 * @param r    - register (instance) number
 */
#define VTSS_IOREG_IX(dev, is32, o, g, gw, r, ro)   VTSS_IOREG(dev, is32, (o) + (((g) * (gw)) + (ro) + (r)))


#define VTSS_IOADDR(t,o) ((((t) - VTSS_IO_CPU) >> 2) + (o))
#define VTSS_IOREG(t,o)  (VTSS_IOADDR(t,o))
```

Comment: Ah I understand now a bit more about #define. with #define func(a,b) realfunc(a,b,1,2,3,1) it is possible to replace func(a,b) with the given function in the code! The \ command can expand the replacement code for the #define . So a whole code segment will be placed inside. The "passed" parameters like a,b are use. The rest parameters/ variables should be available in the code where the makro is written

Comment: When I use some simple stuff it works  sry somethi <\br>                                                                               `[code] static vtss_rc venice_line_sd10g_tx_cfg_lan10g(vtss_state_t *vtss_state, vtss_port_no_t port_no)
{
    u32 d_filter = 0;
    if (vtss_state->phy_10g_state[port_no].mode.serdes_conf.use_conf) {
        d_filter  = vtss_state->phy_10g_state[port_no].mode.serdes_conf.d_filter;
    } else {
        d_filter  = 0x7DF820;
    }
ioreg_blk b;
u32 as=1;
TEST_RD(port_no,&b,&as);
CSR_RD(port_no,&b,&as); [/code]`

Comment: sry my acc is banned or something cant write an answer to my question but here I write it in the comments:

Comment: Ok the reason why

CSR_RD(port_no, VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS(0), test2); 

appears is because of the second parameter VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS It is a Makro which should insert a appropriate return value. But actually this return value is never set. Behind CSR_RD on the other hand lies a function _csr_rd(vtss_state, p, io_reg, value); there the first parameter not be "passed" by the MAKRO.

Comment: It should be in the code. It would be Parameter 1 for _csr_rd. Now parameter p is the second. In the main code it is the first : " CSR_RD(port_no, ". 
Then the Marko with the wrong / with no appropriate return value comes. It is the third! parameter of _csr_rd and only the second of CSR_RD. This was my confusion. Another big point is: In my code is a correct function for the MAKRO VTSS_VENICE_DEV4_SERDES6G_ANA_STATUS_SERDES6G_PLL_STATUS. But I have to place it by myself - it is undefined.. : sry cant write more comments it is blocked by  the system..............xD